# Не применяется margin

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Не могу понять, почему не работает margin-right для input

```css
.search {
  width: 200px;
  height: 28px;
  border: 1px solid #444;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.search__wrapp {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.search__dropdown-ico {
  float: right;
}

.search__input {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  margin-right: 40px;
  /* не работает  */
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="search">
  <div class="search__wrapp">
    <span class="search__dropdown-ico">v</span>
    <input type="text" class="search__input">
  </div>
</div>
```

[Пример на сodepen](https://codepen.io/n_ds/pen/XwqgyZ)

Comment: Применяется. Опишите что хотите получить, а то вообще не понятно зачем вам margin сдался

Comment: @DaemonHK для выделения места под .search__dropdown-ico

Comment: К `.search` добавьте `display:inline-block; min-width:200px; width:auto;`, а затем меняйте margin сколько душе угодно

Comment: @DaemonHK В таком случае ширина инпута не меняется, а происходит изменение ширины блока search, ширина которого должна быть фиксированной.
Нужного поведения добился заменой input на div, но это только для примера.

Comment: @DaemonHK Идеальное поведение, но должен быть инпут https://codepen.io/n_ds/pen/XwqgyZ

Comment: Странная верстка, если честно. Почему иконка справа, а потом флоатится налево? Зачем вам маргин нужен?

Answer (score 1):

На дворе разгар 21 века, использовать `float` преступление, когда есть `flex && grid`

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.search {
  display: inline-flex;
  height: 28px;
  border: 1px solid #444;
}

.search__wrapp {
  display: inline-flex;
}

.search__input {
  margin-right: 40px;
}

.search__dropdown-ico{
  order: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="search">
  <div class="search__wrapp">
    <span class="search__dropdown-ico">v</span>
    <input type="text" class="search__input">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Экстрасенс mode on.

Не работает, потому что у вашего блока `search` есть строгое ограничение `width: 200px`. Наверно самым простым вариантом будет, сделать его `240px`:

```css
.search {
  width: 240px; height: 28px;
  border: 1px solid #444;
  box-sizing: border-box; 
}
.search__wrapp { height: 100%; width: 100%; }
.search__dropdown-ico { float: right; }
.search__input {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="search">
  <div class="search__wrapp">
    <span class="search__dropdown-ico">v</span>
    <input type="text" class="search__input">
  </div>
</div>
```

Или, можно убрать ограничение ширины у этого блока, 

и дать ему `.search { display: inline-block; }` тогда margin-right будет работать:

```css
.search {
  display: inline-block; height: 28px;
  border: 1px solid #444;
  box-sizing: border-box; 
}
.search__wrapp { height: 100%; width: 100%; }
.search__dropdown-ico { float: right; }
.search__input {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  margin-right: 80px; 
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="search">
  <div class="search__wrapp">
    <span class="search__dropdown-ico">v</span>
    <input type="text" class="search__input">
  </div>
</div>
```